# Are there some research papers about text-to-set generation?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, generative-models, generalization

I have googled but find no results.

Text-to-(word)set generation or sequence-to-(token)set generation.

For example, input a text and then output the tags for this text:

`'Peter is studying English'` --> `{'good behavior','person','doing something'}`

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds as either 1) a funky text summarization problem or 2) a multi-class classification problem (where you just don't have a dataset for it yet).

Comment: Also can consider semantic parsing methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these papers below and google keywords: `Multi-label Classification`.

```
X-BERT: eXtreme Multi-label Text Classification with BERT
HAXMLNet: Hierarchical Attention Network for Extreme Multi-Label Text Classification
SGM: Sequence Generation Model for Multi-label Classification
Ranking-Based Autoencoder for Extreme Multi-label Classification
AttentionXML: Label Tree-based Attention-Aware Deep Model for High-Performance Extreme Multi-Label Text Classification
```

Also check out the code below:

https://github.com/chenyuntc/PyTorchText